# Доступ к списку в AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, flask

Используется фреймворк Flask. Есть AJAX запрос. На сервер данные отправляется нормально, и сервер также отправляет данные в ответ, с этим проблем нет, но:

`alert(response)` возвращает `[object Object]`.

`alert(response.data[0])` возвращает `undefined`.

```
   function requestFromCalendar() {   
        var first = selected[0];
        var second = selected[1];
        first.month = first.month+1;
        second.month = second.month+1;
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                first: JSON.stringify(first),
                second: JSON.stringify(second)
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/get_selected_values'
            }).done(function(response) {
                alert(response);
                alert(response.data[0]);

        })
    }

@app.route('/get_selected_values', methods=['POST'])
def get_selected_values():
    values = request.form.get("first")
    first_date = json.loads(values)
    values = request.form.get("second")
    second_date = json.loads(values)

    t = time(0, 0, 0, 0)
    d = date(year=first_date['year'], day=first_date['day'], month=first_date['month'])

    start_date = datetime.combine(d, t)
    start_date = start_date + timedelta(microseconds=123456)

    d = date(year=second_date['year'], day=second_date['day'], month=second_date['month'])

    end_date = datetime.combine(d, t)
    end_date = end_date + timedelta(microseconds=123432)

    data = fetch_selected_date(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, login=current_user.get_id())
    if data:
        return jsonify({'data': data})
    return jsonify({'data': []})
```

Почему не удается увидеть ответные данные от сервера? Как это  исправить?

**EDIT1**

```
console.log(response)
```

выводит

> {data: Array(0)}

и

```
console.log(response.data[0])
```

выводит

> undefined

**EDIT2**

Данные точно есть в `data`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлен `print data` в код Питона. В консоле вывод значений.

**EDIT3**

Согласно ответу меняю код на pyhton и js. Но данные так и не могу получить.

python:

```
...
data = fetch_selected_date(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, login=current_user.get_id())
    data = json.dumps(data)
    return data
```

js:

```
 $.ajax({
        data: {
            first: JSON.stringify(first),
            second: JSON.stringify(second)
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/get_selected_values'
        }).done(function(response) {
        var result = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log('result:'+result);   // выдает ответ: result:"[]"
        //если console.log('result:'+result[0]);  то ответ будет: result:"

    })
```

Как исправить такое положение?

Comment: вместо `alert` используйте `console.log(response)` и смотрите в консоли браузера, в вашем случае `alert` пытается вывести объект, а должен выводить строковое значение.

Comment: По поводу `console.log(response.data[0]) `, у вас выводится `undefined`, потому что `response.data` - это пустой массив, а вы пытаетесь получить элемент из пустого массива. Вам необходимо изменить параметры `ajax-запроса` или данные в вашей базе, которые должны вернуться в результате запроса.

Comment: Данные точно есть и массив data - не пустой. См. Edit 2

Comment: возможно проблема в том что вам нужно использовать JSON.stringify(response)

Answer (score 1):

что на ноде, что на клиенте

https://github.com/axios/axios

что-то вроде этого

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
let first,second;
first = JSON.stringify(first),
second = JSON.stringify(second)
console.log(first,second)// смотрим что передаём
axios.post('/user', {
    first,second,
})
.then(function (response) {
    // в случае ноды, ставим здесь брейкпоинт(при наличии отладчика)
    // и смотрим переменную response
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
</script>
```

---

а теперь к вопросу, предполагаю, что виной всему строчка

```
dataType: 'json'
```

возможно `$` ожидает данные в формате json а получает массив, если это так - масcив поместить в переменную объекта, например qwa

```
resp = {
    qwa:[1,2,3]
}
```

так же не забыть привести к строке

```
resp = json.dumps(resp) - питон
resp = JSON.stringify(resp) - js
```

перед тем как вернуть напечатать

```
print(type(resp) is str) // проверяем, должна быть строка
print(resp)
return resp // возвращаем
```

---

да! есть нюанс, например у fetch
response.json это Promise

---

ещё, как вариант, серверу необходимо передать
content-type: application/json

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Посмотрите пожалуйста на Edit 3

Comment: Используется фреймворк Flask